# WebSocket serverSocket.Accept() doesn't trigger

Tags: c#, websocket, network-programming

I am trying to send `strings` to a server using Synchronous WebSockets in a C# console application. The following code works flawlessly on `127.0.0.1` but doesn't work on any real server I tried. The result I get is that the client connects to the IP/Port and sends `strings` with no errors, but `_serverSocket.Accept();` never triggers when `_clientSocket.Connect(_IP, _PORT);` is called.

Also, if `serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT));` is not called, then the sender gets an error (*as expected*) when trying to connect. So it seems like it should work and the port is also working.

I tried using a variety of servers. The one in the sample code below is taken from https://server.pro/

So, the question is, why doesn't `_serverSocket.Accept();` trigger, since the sender can connect and send `strings` with no errors ?

```
private static Socket _serverSocket, _clientSocket;
private const int _PORT = 40288;
//this IP doesn't work, but 127.0.0.1 works flawlessly
private static IPAddress _IP = IPAddress.Parse("37.187.143.226"); 

//---------sender (client) code---------
_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);
//connects, no errors appear
_clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(_IP), _PORT);

//sends strings to the server, no errors appear
while (true) { 
    Console.Write("Enter text to send: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    _clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
    Console.WriteLine("Sent!");
}

//-------listener (server) code--------     
_serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);
_serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT)); 
_serverSocket.Listen(10);
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client socket to connect");    
_clientSocket = _serverSocket.Accept(); //never triggers
Console.WriteLine("Socket accepted, waiting for data...");
```

Comment: Socket is probably not in listening mode. Have you tried another port?

Comment: @MaheshKava What does "socket is not in listening mode" mean ? Can I set it to be in listening mode ? Do you mean the server/port is not in listening mode ?  If server wasn't in listening mode then shouldn't I get errors when connecting and sending `strings` to the server/port ? From  https://server.pro website, I get an IP:Port, so I don't have the choice to try another port. [This tool that checks if ports are open](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) showed me that when I registered the server, the port also opened.

Comment: what i meant Socket Accept listens for a connection unless something is blocking it, ideally should throw SocketException if not in listening mode. Do you get timeout errors?

Comment: @MaheshKava No I said I don't get any errors at all. Doesn't the fact that the port is open mean that it is listening as well ? I just need a server with a working port, if you can recommend any. For this purpose I tried using the free minecraft servers from https://server.pro website.

Comment: This is very strange because if I take literally what you wrote this can't happen. There must be something more to this issue that is not described here. What happens when you don't start the server and execute the client? The Connect call should throw. Post the exception ToString().

Comment: @usr Again as I said multiple times, I am using servers from https://server.pro I can't "physically not start the server" (if that's what you mean) because I don't have control of that server. I explained in my question what happens when I change the code in various ways. If there is a problem on the server side, what could that problem be ? Considering that the port is open and client can connect and send, but `serverSocket.Accept()` doesn't trigger ?

Comment: You said you tested with not calling Bind. It seems you control the server code?! What exception do you get when Bind is not called?

Comment: @usr The client and the server code are called locally from my computer from a `client.exe` and a `server.exe`. Am I supposed to do something differently ?

Comment: Seems fine... What's the point of you telling that to me? What exception do you get when Bind is not called?

Comment: @usr You just told be "it seems you control the server code" and I made it clear that I don't, by telling you that "I call ALL the code locally". I actually don't get any exceptions or errors, when bind is not called (I did get errors on 127.0.0.1`). Is the server code supposed to be physically copied and run on the actual server machine ? Is this what I am doing wrong ? How does that "Seems fine" when it doesn't work ?

Comment: Shiro, we seem to misunderstand each other a lot. All my comments are made in good faith.; The server code must run on the machine that you want to connect to. That would be the machine that has IP 37.187.143.226. Does that make sense?

Comment: @usr Yes it does make sense. This is what none ever mentioned in any tutorials about networking code, because everything was running on `127.0.0.1`. So both the client and server code were called locally. Which is why I said before "The client and the server code are running locally from my computer" and you said that it "seems fine" this is what made me even more confused. Now, from our conversation I understand that I should be running that code from the server side and not locally, and this is the reason that `serverSocket.Accept()` never triggers

Comment: Correct. This is the first time I see this particular mistake so it took me a while to find out what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code must run on the machine that you want to connect to. That would be the machine that has IP 37.187.143.226.

So either run everything locally and use target IP "localhost" or run the server on that other box and use the 37 IP.

Also be aware that often firewalls and routers must be configured to allow access.

Comment: How is this code supposed to be called assuming I have a `serverSide.cs` file copied on the server (or would I need a pre-compiled version of it ?). How would I run that ?

Comment: You some need to get the exe there. Probably, that means compiling on your machine and copying the file. But it doesn't matter how the exe gets there. cs files are not executable because an exe is potentially comprised of many cs files.

Comment: I would also need to call a `mono myexe.exe` command from the shell ? Is this accurate ? Would there be an easier or better way ?

Comment: I don't know much about mono. Sounds about right but that's not what I'm good at.